# Different image sizes in tensorflow with batch_size =1

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to achieve a python class, which can load a `tensorflow model` and implement a inference. However I have no idea about how can I input image with variable image size. :(

```
class ArtGenerater():
    def __init__(self,model_path):
            self.model_path = model_path
            # vary shape?
            self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(1,512,512,3))
            self.gen = model.resnet(self.x)
            self.out = tf.saturate_cast(self.gen,tf.uint8)

            self.sess = tf.Session()
            file = tf.train.lastest_checkpoint(self.model_path)
            saver = tf.train.Saver()
            saver.restore(self.sess,file)
    def pic(self,image_path):
            img =np.asarray(Image.open(image_path)).astype(np.float32)
            img = np.expand_dims(img,0)
            output_t = self.sess.run(self.out,feed_dict={self.x:img})
            return output_t
```

Now I just use `tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(1,512,512,3))`,
but my image have different sizes(eg. 1000*900).

How can i achieve this function?
Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Thank you everyone.I have solved problem by using:

```py
x = tf.placeholder(tf.string)
img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(x,channels=3)
```

And this can feed network (my `ConvNet` include many `conv2d` & `conv2d_tranpose`) with different image size. :)

Comment: You could feed them as jpeg strings into tensorflow and use decode jpeg op to enforce uniform size

Comment: good idea.thank you very much,i will try.

Answer (score 4):

Basically you can define a various size input using None as follows

```
self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, None, None, 3])
```

and then you can feed different input

```
feed_dict={self.x: current_data} etc..
```

But be careful about your neural net structure. If you flatten your last conv layer as input to the first dense layer then your network only works at that size, and you need to either stretch or crop the image to make it work.

A more flexible approach is to use something like [Global Average Pooling](https://www.quora.com/What-is-global-average-pooling) or [Spatial Pyramid Pooling](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.4729) which both fix this problem.

Comment: This thirst dimension is the batch size. This will not help with getting different image size as asked. It's possible to have placeholders that match each individual image size but then, as you mention, the net structure should be able to handle various input sizes.

Comment: It's often used for batch size definition but it's totally up to you... As it's possible to resize\crop image with tf operations after, so you can simply feed the graph with images of different sizes, using None. Anyway, i prefer to split data processing and NN use..

Comment: I just care about the different image size(not batch_size).and I solved the problem by using`img = tf.placeholder(tf.string)``image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img,channels=3)`

Comment: @AlexJoz is this what's used on tensorflow's inception5h model? it is used on tf's deepdream tutorial and does take variable input size